# Is it possible to parametarize query that has a concatenation variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, parameters

As learning php and sql injections, I would like to parametize my queries for safe and secure website app. however, mine does not work I try to parametize my update and select my query but I didn't achieved the goal to make the program working.

The current output is throwing an error the `?` is not found

As of now here is my code, am I missing something that does not work?

```
<?php  
//connection
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostserver","username","");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname');

if (isset($_POST['qrname'])) {
    $qrid = $_POST['qrid'];

    //Query No. 1
    $qrQuery = "SELECT * FROM scratch_cards WHERE code='$qrid' ";
    $qrQuery_run = mysqli_query($connection,$qrQuery);

    //Query No. 2
    $qrQuery2 = "UPDATE scratch_cards SET status = 'U' WHERE code='$qrid' ";
    $qrQuery_run2 = mysqli_query($connection,$qrQuery2);
    $qrQuery2->bind_param("s", $qrid);
    $qrQuery2->execute();

    while ($qrRow = mysqli_fetch_array($qrQuery_run)) {
        $txtQrvalue = $qrRow['amount'];
        $txtQrstatus = $qrRow['status'];

        // QUERY TO UPDATE THE VALUE
        // BIND AND PARAMETIZE MY QUERY
        $qrQuery3 = $db->parepare("UPDATE shopusers SET ewallet = ewallet + " . (0+?) . " WHERE id = '?' ");
        $qrQuery3->bind_param("ii", $txtQrvalue, $id);
        $qrQuery3->execute(); 
        //END
    }
```

Comment: You can't quote the placeholders. The query should be `UPDATE shopusers SET ewallet = ewallet + ? WHERE id = ?`

Comment: @Qirel , how about the query 1 and 2? same bindings/??

Comment: @Qirel , another question, do I need to bind the while loop? thank you

Comment: You don't need to bind static values like `SET status = 'U'`. But definitively the IDs as they are variables. Using a `SELECT` you also need to bind the results.

Comment: @Qirel, the page does not load :(

Comment: Your `$id` variable is also undefined. Where do you get that from?

Comment: @Qirel , just forgot it .. it was this `$id= $_SESSION['id'];`

Comment: @Qirel, Hi, i also might asks this one, i am not sure if this while loop is correct `while($qrRow = mysqli_fetch_array($qrQuery_run)){` because I have `$qrQuery_run = mysqli_query($connection,$qrQuery);` which I  think it is not needed on the bindings and paremetizign query

Comment: You need to bind all your queries containing variables. Select statements too.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question and code right, you can reduce this down to two queries using a `JOIN` instead, that way you can get rid of the `SELECT` statement. Use prepared statements for both.

I also specified your connection's charset to UTF-8 (which you should set for your PHP and HTML headers, and your database-tables too).

```php
<?php 
$connection = mysqli_connect("hostserver","username","");
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'dbname');
$connection->set_charset("utf8");

if (isset($_POST['qrname'])) {
    $qrid = $_POST['qrid'];

    $sql = "UPDATE scratch_cards SET status = 'U' WHERE code=?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $qrid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    $sql = "UPDATE shopusers su
               INNER JOIN scratch_cards sc
                 ON sc.qrid = su.code
               SET su.ewallet = su.ewallet + sc.amount,
                   sc.status = 'U'
               WHERE sc.code = ?";
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $qrid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: can you please include the `while` loop please? it is just important thank you

Comment: You don't need it with the query using `JOIN`s. See the second query is using an `UPDATE` with `JOIN`. You might have a different `ON` clause, I'm not quite sure on your database-structure. This is the general idea though.

Comment: They are aliases for the tables. Means we don't have to type `shopusers` everytime, we can just say `su`.

Comment: im not really familiar with `JOIN` statements.. can I ask if i'll ad `UPDATE shopusers AS su` or.. `su` is like a variable?

Comment: cause the syntax of the update query has a different colors .. so it might be a wrong syntax?

Comment: "Didnt' work" is not very descriptive. I can't see what you see on your end - you need to describe *how* it doesn't work. Any error-messages? If not, did you check your error-logs? What happens, what doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

we have the foll syntax in PDO bind param, where i have put your update query as an example and it works perfectly fine. **Try searching for named parameter binding**

```
<?php


$user = 'root';
$pass = 'xxxx';
$DB = 'test';
$host = 'localhost';

$mysqlConnection = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$DB, $user, $pass);
$mysqlConnection->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = 'update info set fname = fname + :fn where id = 1';

$stmt = $mysqlConnection->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':fn', '100');
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->rowCount();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the query you wanted to run using mysqli bind params???

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'xxxx';
$DB = 'test';
$host = 'localhost';

$sql = 'update info set fname =  fname + ? where id = 1';

$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $DB);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("i", $val);
$val = 100;
$stmt->execute();
printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
exit;
```